# How to control self.play run at specific time point

Tags: manim

Suppose there are two self.play statements, the first starts at 1s, I want to the seconds start at precisely 3s from the begining.

Currently I use self.wait to control the steps:

```
self.wait(1)
self.play...... # first animation
self.wait(2)    # because 1 + 2 = 3
self.play...... # second animation
```

However, because the first animation will take sometime (e.g. 1.5s) to finish, actually the second animation will start at 1 + 1.5 + 2 = 4.5s.

How can I make the second self.play start run at precisely 3s from the begining?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean, this?

```py
class SuccessionExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        number_line=NumberLine(x_min=-2,x_max=2)
        triangle=RegularPolygon(3,start_angle=-PI/2)\
                   .scale(0.2)\
                   .next_to(number_line.get_left(),UP,buff=SMALL_BUFF)
        text_1=TextMobject("1")\
               .next_to(number_line.get_tick(-1),DOWN)
        text_2=TextMobject("2")\
               .next_to(number_line.get_tick(0),DOWN)
        text_3=TextMobject("3")\
               .next_to(number_line.get_tick(1),DOWN)
        text_4=TextMobject("4")\
               .next_to(number_line.get_tick(2),DOWN)

        self.add(number_line)
        self.play(ShowCreation(triangle))
        self.wait(0.3)

        self.play(
                    #The move of the triangle starts
                    ApplyMethod(triangle.shift,RIGHT*4,rate_func=linear,run_time=4),

                    AnimationGroup(
                        Animation(Mobject(),run_time=1),#<- one second pause
                        Write(text_1),lag_ratio=1       #<- then start Write animation
                    ),
                    AnimationGroup(
                        Animation(Mobject(),run_time=2),#<- two seconds pause
                        Write(text_2),lag_ratio=1       #<- then start Write animation
                    ),
                    AnimationGroup(
                        Animation(Mobject(),run_time=3),#<- three seconds pause
                        Write(text_3),lag_ratio=1       #<- then start Write animation
                    ),
                    AnimationGroup(
                        Animation(Mobject(),run_time=4),#<- four seconds pause
                        Write(text_4),lag_ratio=1       #<- then start Write animation
                    ),
            )

        self.wait()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, do you mean the run_time parameter can be used to control the time consumed by each animation? or just a pause during the pause no animation is playing?

Comment: Each animation has a certain duration, some last 2 seconds, others 1.5, etc. Under normal conditions, when you write:

`self.play(Animation1(mobjects), Animation2(mobjects))`

They all start at the same time, and you can control the duration time of each with run_time:


`self.play(Animation1(mobjects, run_time = t1), Animation2(mobjects, run_time = t2))`

When the longest animation has ended then the next command is followed, which can be a `play` or a `wait`. The code above is an example of how you can start an animation in the middle of another.

Comment: In this video I explain it better:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km09KYWb9ag&t=5m4s

Comment: This doesn't really make the animations start at a fixed time from the beginning; they start a fixed time after the previous animation finished.